# JUnit hamcrest Long comparison

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have the follwoing test code:

```
Page<Long> users = userService.findAllUserIdsWithLocationsWithoutCategories(pageable);
assertEquals(1, users.getTotalElements());
assertThat(users.getContent(), hasSize(1));
assertThat(users.getContent(), containsInAnyOrder(user5.getId()));
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable with items [<132L>] in any order
     but: not matched: <132>
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Does `getContent()` by any chance return a `Collection<Integer>`?

Comment: no, it returns `List<Long>`

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems that either `users.getContents()` or `user5.getId()` returns an `int` or `Integer`.

Comment: And `User.getId()` returns long also? It much seems that list has one Long <132L> and it does not match <132> , Integer ?

Comment: Hamcrest does not support auto-boxing (e.g. from `Integer` to `Long`), but you could [overload a Matcher to widen/narrowing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437839/how-to-use-primitive-autoboxing-widening-with-hamcrest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Actual return types

You are calling `getContent()` on return value [`Page<Long>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html). This will return a `List<Long>` as the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--) state:

> List<T> getContent()
>
> Returns the page content as List.

#### Suitable matcher

So you can use *Hamcrest*'s [Matchers for Collections](https://www.baeldung.com/hamcrest-collections-arrays).
I would use `hasItem()` to check if the one item (e.g. `user5.getId()`) is contained in the list.

#### Matching the same types

But pay attention to the argument type you pass to `hasItem()`. The *expected* value should be of type `Long` or `long` (autoboxing), since your *actual* elements of `List<Long>` have type `Long`.

What is the return type of your argument `user5.getId()`?

The error-message shows you are expecting an `int` or `Integer` (because missing `L` for Long):

> not matched: <132>

Whereas your List returns elements of `Long` (hence suffix `L` in the error-message):

> iterable with items [<132L>]

#### Solution: cast or re-design

You can either cast the expected `getId()` to the required type `Long`:
`assertThat(users.getContent(), containsInAnyOrder( (Long) user5.getId() ));`

Or you bravely re-design the method under test to return `Page<Integer>`. Rational behind: since most IDs are implemented as  `Integer` (see `user5.getId()`) all related methods (like `findAllUserIdsWithLocationsWithoutCategories`) should respect that type in their signature and return `Integer`s.